# Bind Dictionary's Value to an element's tooltip in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a dictionary in which key and value both are string type.

Key stores the name of UI element and value stores the tooltip for that element.

Code :

```
static Dictionary<string, string> tooltips = new Dictionary<string, string>();
tooltips.Add("Add", "Adds the digits");
tooltips.Add("Multiply", "Multiply the digits");
tooltips.Add("Divide", "Divide the digits");
```

This dictionary is contained in a static class.

I want to bind this dictionary to a xaml page which contains buttons. Can anyone please tell me how can I bind the tooltip to the specified element in xaml?

Comment: what is key and value here?

Comment: key is element's name. for example button's name is "Add" and value represents the tooltip to be applied on that element like "Adds the digits".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Solution.

You need to add TextBLock inside the Button to display Tooltip, so your XAML looks like this,

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="btnAdd" Width="75">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <TextBlock  x:Name="Add"></TextBlock>
            </ToolTip>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="btnMultiply" Width="75">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip >
                <TextBlock  Name="Multiply"></TextBlock>
            </ToolTip>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="btnDivide" Width="75">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip >
                <TextBlock Name="Divide"></TextBlock>
            </ToolTip>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </Button>
 </Grid>
```

And here to display ToolTip

```
        tooltips.Add("Add", "Adds the digits");
        tooltips.Add("Multiply", "Multiply the digits");
        tooltips.Add("Divide", "Divide the digits");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> name in tooltips)
        {
            TextBlock tt = LayoutRoot.FindName(name.Key.ToString()) as TextBlock;
            tt.Text = name.Value.ToString();
        }
       foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> name in tooltips)
        {
        TextBlock tt = LayoutRoot.FindName(name.Key.ToString()) as TextBlock;
        tt.Text = name.Value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: The question is how to implement binding, not to do this code behind.